# cannot understand why these two codes dont have the same output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

input1 :

```
for i in range(5):
    lst = [0,0,0,0,0]
    lst[i] = 1
    print(lst)
```

output1 :

```
1, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

input2 :

```
mainlst = [0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(5):
    templst = mainlst
    templst[i] = 1
    print(templst)
```

output2 :

```
1, 0, 0, 0, 0
1, 1, 0, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Why does assigning a value, to a variable,  1) as a list, and 2) as a variable(whose value is the same as the list), not have the same output
i expected the two to give the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `[0,0,0,0,0]` constructs a new list object each time it is executed. Your first example constructs a new list of five zeros each time the loop executes `lst = [0,0,0,0,0]`.

In your second example, `mainlst = [0,0,0,0,0]` is executed just one time. The assignment, `templst = mainlst` doesn't do anything except set the local variable `tmplst` to refer to the same, already-existing list object to which `mainlst` refers. The second loop keeps re-using the same list on each iteration.

---

**Update**

> if i also print 'mainlst' along with 'templst', the list 'mainlst' also changes to the same as 'templst' where as in my code i havent changed the value of mainlst anywhere

`mainlst` is not a list. `tmplist` is not a list. `[0,0,0,0,0]` is not a list. A Python list is an *object* that exists in a space called the "heap." `mainlst` and `tmplist` are *variables,* but in Python (unlike C or C++) it is not possible for a variable to hold a list. A variable can only *refer to* a list.

`[0,0,0,0,0]` is an *expression* that constructs a new list and returns a reference to it.
`mainlst=[0,0,0,0,0]` is a *statement* that;

1. creates a new variable, `mainlst`,
2. *evaluates* the `[0,0,0,0,0]` expression, creating a new list, and then
3. stores a reference to the new list into the new variable.

`templst=mainlst` is a statement that creates another new variable, `templist`, and causes it to refer to the *same list object* as `mainlst`.

When you write `templst[i]=1` that doesn't *also* change `mainlst`. It changes the one, and only list to which *both* variables refer.

If you want to create a *new* list—a copy of the list to which `mainlst` refers—then do what @russhoppa told you to do: `templst=mainlst.copy()`. The `copy` function constructs a new list with all the same contents as the given list, and then it returns a reference to the new list.

Comment: mainlst = [0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(5):
        templst = mainlst
        templst[i] = 1
        print(mainlst, templst)

in my second example if i also print 'mainlst' along with 'templst', the list 'mainlst' also changes to the same as 'templst' where as in my code i havent changed the value of mainlst anywhere

Comment: @MrTraitor, See the "Update" to my answer, above.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you're referencing the `mainlst` every time. If you change your code to:

```py
mainlst = [0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(5):
    templst = mainlst.copy()
    templst[i] = 1
    print(templst)
```

You'll get the same results. Look up more about python arrays and deep vs shallow copies.

https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/